# WP Category Archive /page/2+ pagination issue 404

Tags: permalinks, pagination, 404-error

Encountered an issue when navigating to archive pages within a category after page 1 of the results via pagination.  This is the standard WP categories and not a custom query.

Working: /category/community/

404: /category/community/page/2

There are various old threads on this topic - which I've exhausted at this point - and I've tried the following tasks with no success in resolving the issue:

1. Disabled all plugins - issue still occurs
2. Switched to default twenty* theme(s) - issue still occurs
3. Setting query params via *pre_get_posts* - issue still occurs
4. Changing Reading Settings / Blog pages show at most (up/down) - issue still occurs

There is something interesting going on with Permalinks:

Not Working: Month and name or /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/

If I change to custom, it works: /%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/

Obviously, changing Permalinks is sort of a ultra last resort on this live site which has been live for a number of years.

Any other paths or insight is appreciated.